# Slicing pandas dataframe on equal column values

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have a pandas df that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0:[1],5:[1],10:[1],15:[1],20:[0],25:[0],
                   30:[1],35:[1],40:[0],45:[0],50:[0]})
df
```

[image]

The column names reflect coordinates. I would like to retrieve the start and end coordinate of columns with consecutive equal numbers.

The output should be something like this:

```
# start,end
0,15 
20,25
30,35
40,50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUCusing `groupby` with `diff` and `cumsum` to split the group

```
s=df.T.reset_index()
s=s.groupby(s[0].diff().ne(0).cumsum())['index'].agg(['first','last'])
Out[241]: 
   first  last
0             
1      0    15
2     20    25
3     30    35
4     40    50
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel like there should also be an easy way to only get the coordinates that correspond to the zeros or alternatively only to the ones. With an output like: 0,15  \n 30,35 for the ones. Do you know how?

Answer (score 1):

`cumsum` to identify group, and `groupby`:

```
s = df.iloc[0].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
(df.columns.to_series()
 .groupby(s).agg(['min','max'])
)
```

Output:

```
   min  max
0          
1    0   15
2   20   25
3   30   35
4   40   50
```